How do I change the title of a Filament infolist?
I have a 'role' resource which has a view route, ie:
RoleResource.php:
class RoleResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Role::class;

    public static function infolist(Infolist $infolist): Infolist
    {
        return $infolist
            ->schema([
                Section::make([
                    TextEntry::make('title'),
                    TextEntry::make('url'),
                ]),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListRoles::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateRole::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditRole::route('/{record}/edit'),
            'view' => Pages\ViewRole::route('/{record}'),
        ];
    }
}

'ViewRole.php`:
class ViewRole extends ViewRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = RoleResource::class;
}

This results in a view page with the title 'View Role':

How can I change this to show a different, dynamic title (such as 'View {title}')?

To change the title of a page to be dynamic, you can override getTitle function on the page class (ViewRole.php) like this:
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable;

public function getTitle(): string|Htmlable
{
    $title = 'Role ' . ($this->record?->name);
    return "View {$title}";
}


Thanks @darkclow4! I'd gone down the rabbit hole looking for a set... function rather than get...!
